# Understanding webcam 's Linux device drivers

Tags: linux-device-driver, webcam, v4l2

As far as I know, device driver is a part of SW that is able to communicate with a particular type of device that is attached to a computer.

In case of a USB webcam, the responsible driver is UVC that supports any UVC compliant device. This means that enables OS or other computer program to access hardware functions without needing to know precise details of the hardware being used.

For this reason, I installed UVC Linux device driver by running:

```
opkg install kernel-module-uvcvideo
```

Webcam has been recognised by Linux kernel: `dev/video0`. However, I still wasn't able to perform video streaming with FFmpeg, as I was missing V4L2 API. I installed V4L2, by configuring kernel.

**My queries are:**

- How UVC driver and V4L2 are linked together?
- What is the purpose of V4L2 API?
- If I haven't installed UVC first, it would be installed with V4L2?

LinuxTV refers: *The uvcvideo driver implementation is adherent only to the V4L2 API*. This means that UVC is part of V4L2 API?

Comment: The UVC driver and V4L2 have a relationship similar to a disk driver and filesystem, or like an Ethernet MAC driver and the protocol stack. The raw data and control of the device provided by the device driver alone does not support a sophisticated interface to make that subsystem truly versatile.  Do you want to keep track of data on disk by sector numbers?  Instead of sockets and protocols, should each process contend for use of the network?  Does your app want to do the encode/decode of the audio & video?  You will find many layered subsystems if you look for them in Linux.

Comment: This question has been answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116904/understanding-webcam-s-linux-device-drivers